# Picking a specific return Type from a type that contains multiples in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type that contains multiple different return types and I would like to create a new Type based on one of its types like this:

```
type GetServerSidePropsResult<P> = {
    props: P | Promise<P>;
} | {
    redirect: Record<string, any>;
} | {
    notFound: true;
}

type Redirect<P> = Pick<GetServerSidePropsResult<P>, { redirect }>
```

This syntax does not work, and I was wondering:

- Is this even possible?
- If yes, is it also possible to get rid of the `P` since we don't need it?

Comment: Why not just create separate types for each of the response types and use those in the union type?

Comment: Those types are coming from Next.js (3rd party library) so I trying to work around this constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility:

```
type Redirect<P> = Extract<GetServerSidePropsResult<P>, { redirect: any }>
```

Note that you need to specify a type for the property, but you can just use `any` for that to allow any of the types that returns that property.

As for removing the type parameter, you can use `any` for the value in `GetServerSidePropsResult<P>` and then remove it from `Redirect`

```
type Redirect = Extract<GetServerSidePropsResult<any>, { redirect: any }>
```